# error adding summary links webpart in page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

i am facing issue with summary links web part in SharePoint 2010 when i try to add  it and click on browse option to add links it is giving me the error

**"Unable to display this webpart.To troubleshoot the problem,open this webpage in a microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persisists ,contact your webserver administrator."**

please let me know any solution for this.I don't have any access to central administration as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the known issue that occurs after installing the patch [KB2844286](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2844286)

According to the Microsoft:

> we released a fix for this issue. Details and download links
>   can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2872441)  which will resolve the issue for Windows 7 SP1
>   and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

---

For more details and how to resolve it follow [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/cc9a557b-93cd-40d5-965c-e0a2f107624d/unable-to-display-this-web-part-error-message-after-patch-kb2844286)

Comment: HI Vadim,Thanks for the reply ,but i don't have access to central admin stuff so is it possible to fix it on other way? any work around?,,thanks

Comment: This error occurs due to a functional issue in .NET Framework 3.5. I believe the installing update from Microsoft or uninstalling KB2844286 will only fix this issue